# Method to identify ipv4 vs ipv6 addresses

Tags: postgresql

I have an ip field in a postgres database defined as an `inet` field.

At the moment, to determine ipv4 vs ipv6, it looks like I can use colon count and/or '.' count to some degree, but there must be a better way, right?

```
COLON_COUNT = (length(ip::text) - length(replace(ip::text, ':', '')));
DOT_COUNT = (length(ip::text) - length(replace(ip::text, '.', '')));
```

What is a clean/good way to determine if a address is ipv4 or ipv6?

Comment: I think if the trailing zeros are not ommitted you could just convert the field into a number and see if the number is less than 2 powers 32 IPv4 or not (IPV6). This means filtering out colons and dots before the number conversion.

Comment: Thats a good idea!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [`family()` function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-net.html#CIDR-INET-FUNCTIONS-TABLE). IPv4 will return 4, IPv6 will return 6.

Comment: great, thanks!  I was looking at that page, but I overlooked this.

Answer (score 1):

I think if the trailing zeros are not ommitted you could just convert the field into a number and see if the number is less than 2 powers 32 IPv4 or not (IPV6).
This means filtering out colons and dots before the number conversion.